# How to add a custom javascript code in a Drupal BLOCK

Tags: javascript

The title says it all. I want to add a series of advertising javascript code like adsense, facebook likebox javascript code.

How can I add a javascript code as a block and put it on sidebar first. Its not working for me even typing the javascript as FULL HTML but instead drupal displays the source code in my sidebar instead of executing it as javascript.

Can I just COPY PASTE the javascript code in Drupal block, is this possible?

Note: I am using Drupal 8

Comment: First do you include any .js file? In chrome Debug function is any error in console. This a bit more strange as Drupal 7/8 will render the js code without problem. When using the Full HTML go to sourch and see is they render as&lt; (html entities)

Comment: @Drupalizeme hi I haven't include it as .js file. I just copy paste it from the block. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you include the js code here?

Comment: @Drupalizeme here it is:

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=611372972302905&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/layoutph" data-width="200" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>

Comment: Its a code for Facebook likebox, tomorrow I need to put an adsense code.

Comment: And this code printed as text in block? Are you using full html? Can you see the source code of the block and verified that it is not rendered as html entities.